# Open Source C++ to C# compiler/converter

Tags: c#, c++, open-source, compiler-construction, converters

Even if it requires manual input. Is there any good-enough option available?

Comment: It's unfortunate that this question was closed. I hope it will someday be migrated to http://softwarereqs.stackexchange.com/, where it can be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about this site, but a little googling found [this](http://code2code.net/).

Comment: I played around with this very briefly... I suppose it might save you a little time, but I'd probably do it manually myself anyhow.

Comment: I found that site but I do not think it is open source.

Comment: Yeah, and I'd be reluctant to put any of my production code on it.

Comment: Still a pretty useful tool to quickly evaluate something you may be thinking of converting

Answer (score 1):

If it was in managed C++ or C++/CLI, you could compile it and then disassemble the assembly into C# using a tool like Reflector. Of course, that's not open source but maybe you can find an open source Reflector-style tool?

If it's native C++, that's much more difficult.